# Check when a task has been completed N number of times?

Tags: php

I am running a script to perform a task N number of times in PHP (downloading and converting file format for N files inputted in a form)

How whould I check when this has finished for all files?

My approach was this:

1. create a text file with only the number 0
2. for each conversion finished add 1
3. check if the number in the .txt file equals N-1

Is this reasonable, or is there a way of doing this that I don't know of?

Thank you

Comment: You can use sessions, cookies and of course files too.

Comment: Certainly possible, but unusual. The "usual" approach is to maintain a job queue (typically inside a database, not a file for performance reasons) and to register every conversion job as a single entry in there. The job itself takes care to mark itself as "done" when terminating. That way you always have a current view on the situation and can even intervene when required. If you need to group jobs somehow (like by triggering request) you can add such information in additional columns in that queue system.

Comment: If all the tasks are executed within the same session you could use a $_SESSION variable for that. If not, writing the counter into a flat file is feasible. But be aware, that the file should be locked while writing it, when concurrent users may start tasks in parallel. Databases usually support locking generically.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go either for the $_SESSION variable or queueing. Thanks a lot